# Unable to run Visual Studio 2008 using Administrator account

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I'm not able to run visual studio 2008 by choosing 'Run as a Administrator' it says 'Application Cannot start'. Any solutions please.

OS : Windows 7 64 bit 
IIS 7.5

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but why would you want to run something like that as an admin?

Comment: MY project is set to 'RUN in IIS'. So visual studio will create Virtual Directories for the websites when the project loads. Only the user with elevated administrator privileges will be able to do it.

Comment: @Mat VS 2008 needs to be admin to register com stuff, deploy web sites, and debug apps that should run elevated. VS 2010 is more elevation-aware. I know many devs (but not me) who ALWAYS run 2008 elevated.

Comment: Try monitoring the launch with ProcMon. I sometimes run VS as admin and it works, so there's no inherent problem in doing so, but ProcMon might give you a hint about the root of the problem if some files are not found. You can also compare the results to a non-admin launch.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across a similar problem myself, where an external tool won't work when VS is run as admin. On my case, the tool tries to access a mapped network folder. Turns out that the mapping applies only for the non-admin login token. Does you VS happen to access a mapped network folder?

See: [Programs may be unable to access some network locations after you turn on User Account Control in Windows Vista or in Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937624). Link includes a possible solution.

BTW, the problem here is probably not VS-specific. Since it seems to regard Windows permissions, it should probably have been asked on ServerFault.